# Self signed SSL certificate for localhost with Apache

Tags: apache, ssl, localhost

I created a self signed SSL certificate with Open SSL and I need a key.pem and a cert.pem file...

Is it true that my server.crt = cert.pem (Certificate) , server.csr = csr.pem (Certificate request), server.key = key.pem (RSA) ? Can I just rename those files or is there a way to convert them ?

Answer (score 0):

.PEM = The PEM extension is used for different types of X.509v3 files which contain ASCII (Base64) data prefixed with a “—– BEGIN …” line.

.CRT = The CRT extension is used for certificates. The certificates may be encoded as ASCII PEM. The CER and CRT extensions are nearly synonymous.

CER = alternate form of .crt (Microsoft Convention) You can use MS to convert .crt to .cer (.both DER encoded .cer, or base64[PEM] encoded .cer).

.KEY = The KEY extension is used both for public and private keys. The keys may be encoded as ASCII PEM.

The only time CRT and CER can safely be interchanged is when the encoding type can be identical.  (ie  PEM encoded CRT = PEM encoded CER).

I used following command to generate .pem file,

1)Generate a CA

/usr/bin/openssl req -out ca.pem -new -x509 -days 1025

This command generates CA file "ca.pem" and CA key "privkey.pem".

2)Generate server certificate/key pair

```
  /usr/bin/openssl genrsa -out server_key.pem 1024
```

3)Generate server cert request

```
  /usr/bin/openssl req -key server_key.pem -new -out server.req
```

4)command to generate generate .srl file

```
 openssl x509 -req -in sguild.req -CA CA.pem -CAkey privkey.pem -CAcreateserial -out sguild.pem
```

5)command to generate server cert .pem

```
/usr/bin/openssl x509 -req -in server.req -CA ca.pem -CAkey privkey.pem -CAserial file.srl -out server_cert.pem -days 730
```

But I need

```
RootCA.pem
server.crt
server.key
```

so I just rename

```
ca.pem (generated from above command) to RootCA.pem

server_cert.pem (generated from above command) to server.crt

server_key.pem (generated from above command) to key.pem
```

and it works for me !!

Comment: Great thanks! But that means that I can als just rename my files.

Comment: Yes you can try it but generate all .pem files by using above commands.

Comment: Hi Abhijeet, I did like you told me and now its working :) Thank you very much!

Comment: Welcome @ Daniel, if you satisfy then please accept my answer !! Thanks in advance